# SwiftUI, how to stop List rolling immediately by code after dragging?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

As the title described. In some case, I want stop the rolling List immediately.
That's easy with UIKit. But there seems no obvious way to do it in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false /// here!
    }
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 1000)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanna stop it when it's still rolling at high speed, that's not related to `bounce`.

Comment: @iaomw If you set `bounces` to false then it won't even roll at high speed. Do you want to stop scrolling when a button is pressed or something?